# _InterlockedCompareExchange optimization

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, x86, x86-64

look at this code

```
extern "C" long _InterlockedCompareExchange(long volatile * _Destination, long _Exchange, long _Comparand);

#define MAGIC 1

// Unlike InterlockedIncrement this function not increment from 0 to 1, but return FALSE

bool TryLock(long* pLock)
{
    long Value = *pLock, NewValue;

    for ( ; Value; Value = NewValue)
    {
        NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(pLock, Value + 1, Value);

        if (
#if MAGIC
            NewValue == Value
#else
            Value == NewValue
#endif
            ) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

are if set `#define MAGIC 0` something changed ? by idea must not be. but if using `CL.EXE` 64bit compiler if we change `NewValue == Value` to `Value == NewValue` (simply long values) - generated code serious changed!

I try this with two version of `CL` - latest `19.00.24210.0` and with `14.00.50727.762` (more than 10 years old - December 2006) I got absolute equal code from both in all tests. compile with flags `cl /c /FA /O1` - so `/O1` optimization (same results with `/Oxs` )

with `MAGIC 1` (`NewValue == Value`)

```
TryLock PROC
    mov eax, [pLock]
    jmp @@
@@loop:
    lea edx, [rax+1]
    lock cmpxchg [pLock], edx
    je  @@exit
@@:
    test    eax, eax
    jne @@loop
    ret
@@exit:
    mov al, 1
    ret
TryLock ENDP
```

but with `MAGIC 0` (`Value == NewValue`)

```
TryLock PROC
    mov r8d, [pLock]
    test    r8d, r8d
    je  @@0
@@loop:
    lea edx, [r8+1]
    mov eax, r8d
    lock cmpxchg [pLock], edx
    cmp r8d, eax        ; !!!!!!!!
    je  @@exit
    test    eax, eax
    mov r8d, eax
    jne @@loop
@@0:
    xor al, al
    ret
@@exit:
    mov al, 1
    ret
TryLock ENDP
```

code become large, but main notable difference in instruction

`cmp Value, NewValue`

after `lock cmpxchg` in second variant. really `lock cmpxchg [p], NewValue` yourself set or reset `ZF` flag and additional `cmp Value, NewValue` become excess. we can omit it if we write in assembly, but on `c/c++` we have no way use `ZF` for condition branch. 
no statements like `ifzf { /* if ZF == 1 */ } else { /* if ZF == 0 */ }` as result we need write `if (NewValue == Value) {} else {}`
and as result must be `cmp NewValue, Value` in generated assembly. but how i discovered for `CL` `x64` (but not for `x86` !) already 10+ years (think all versions) do next

this code

```
NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(p, fn(OldValue), OldValue);
if (OldValue == NewValue) ...
```

converted to

```
mov eax, OldValue
lock cmpxchg [p], fn(OldValue)
mov NewValue, eax
cmp OldValue, eax ; !!!!
jne @@
....
```

but this code

```
NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(p, fn(OldValue), OldValue);
if (NewValue == OldValue) ...
```

converted to

```
mov eax, OldValue
lock cmpxchg [p], fn(OldValue)
mov NewValue, eax
jne @@
...
```

so `CL` understand `cmpxchg` semantic and can do optimization, but only in some case.

i test this feature in several test functions and everywhere got the same result for both (very old and new `CL` )

```
extern "C" long _InterlockedCompareExchange(long volatile * _Destination, long _Exchange, long _Comparand);

typedef long (*FN)(long* pLock, long Value);

#define MAGIC 1

void TestZF1(long* pLock)
{
    long Value = *pLock, NewValue;

    do 
    {
        Value++;
        NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(pLock, Value ^ 1, Value);
    } while (
#if MAGIC
        NewValue != Value
#else
        Value != NewValue
#endif
        );
}

long TestZF2(long* pLock, FN fn1, FN fn2)
{
    long Value = *pLock, NewValue;

    NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(pLock, Value ^ 1, Value);

    return (
#if MAGIC
        NewValue == Value
#else
        Value == NewValue
#endif
        ? fn1 : fn2) (pLock, NewValue);
}
```

and generated assembly:

```
TestZF1 PROC
    mov r8d, DWORD PTR [rcx]
@@loop:
    add r8d, 1
    mov edx, r8d
    mov eax, r8d
    xor edx, 1
    lock cmpxchg [rcx], edx
IF !MAGIC
    cmp r8d,eax     ; ! in TestZF1 different exactly in this instruction
ENDIF
    jne @@loop
    ret 0
TestZF1 ENDP

IF MAGIC

TestZF2 PROC
    mov r9d, [rcx]
    mov eax, [rcx]
    xor r9d, 1
    lock cmpxchg [rcx], r9d
    cmove   r8, rdx
    mov edx, eax
    jmp r8
TestZF2 ENDP

ELSE

TestZF2 PROC
    mov r10d, [rcx]
    mov r9d, r10d
    xor r9d, 1
    mov eax, r10d
    lock cmpxchg [rcx], r9d
    cmp r10d, eax   ; !!!!!!!!
    cmove   r8, rdx     
    mov edx, eax
    jmp r8
TestZF2 ENDP

ENDIF
```

several questions:

- why `CL` `x64` optimize case `if (NewValue == Value)` but not
  optimize `if (Value == NewValue)` ?
- this is consciously, specially designed, or it was suddenly and
  unknown ?
- why `CL` `x86` not do this optimization ? how minimum in all my tests
  `cmp Value,NewValue` instruction exist
- are possible write code on `c/c++` ,without assembler, for implement
  this on x86 with `CL` ?
- interesting - are another `c/c++` compilers have this kind of
  optimization for `_InterlockedCompareExchange[Pointer]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - why CL x64 optimize case if (NewValue == Value) but not optimize if (Value == NewValue) ?
> - this is consciously, specially designed, or it was suddenly and unknown ?

I'm convinced it is a bug, so I've [reported it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/missed-optimization-of-interlockedcompareexchange/1545924).

If they respond, we will know if this is a bug or not.

> - why CL x86 not do this optimization ? how minimum in all my tests cmp Value,NewValue instruction exist

x86 performance may be not optimized to the same level as x86-64, as it is of secondary importance. Though may be reported as another missed optimization bug.

> - are possible write code on c/c++ ,without assembler, for implement this on x86 with CL ?

Apparently not. But `clang-cl` that ships with Visual Studio 2019 and supposed to emulate CL very closely seem to do better. It is also affected by `MAGIC`, but when it is enabled, it produces better code on x86.

> - interesting - are another c/c++ compilers have this kind of optimization for _InterlockedCompareExchange[Pointer] ?

Other compilers have separate `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` and `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`, and they implement this optimization for `bool` version https://godbolt.org/z/j97aEG5GY

---

Note that `_InterlockedCompareExchange` as well as `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` are non-standard, and there are C standard and C++ standard alternatives.

The corresponding standard function returns both boolean directly, and observed value indirectly:

- In C, it is [`atomic_compare_exchange_strong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange), returns `_Bool`, and observed value is returned by pointer where you pass expected
- In C++ it is [`std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), returns `bool`, observed value is returned by reference instead of expected

These standard alternatives are likely to have `_InterlockedCompareExchange` or  `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` under the hood though.

Regarding optimizations:

- GCC and clang optimize this in C: https://godbolt.org/z/hsnMzE689. Unfortunately MSVC does not have `<stdatomic.h>` C header yet
- GCC and clang and MSVC optimize this in C++: https://godbolt.org/z/WfjaajE9W

Comment: thank for answer. by fact `compare_exchange_strong` of course internal use `_InterlockedCompareExchange` - https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/atomic#L949
and here is the same. possible build and more short demo - compare https://godbolt.org/z/jvxrcenW1 and https://godbolt.org/z/P8d1Wc4co - different is in `(_Prev_bytes == _Expected_bytes)` vs `(_Expected_bytes == _Prev_bytes)`

Comment: hard say are form `if (_Prev_bytes == _Expected_bytes)` selected by chance or consciously. but this form generate bit better code - without superfluous cmp instruction

Comment: I suspect that `if (observed == expected)` is just more natural form than `if (expected == observed)`. The same as `if (handle == NULL)` is more natural, though some prefer `if (NULL == handle)` to avoid `if (handle = NULL)` mistake. So in `std::atomic` or in other places it was usually written as `if (observed == expected)`, and then optimization was implemented for exactly this form, and was missed for the other form.

Comment: @RbMm, I've got a reply, the missing optimization is indeed just a bug https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/missed-optimization-of-interlockedcompareexchange/1545924#T-N1651390